# Dynamically set the thread pool size for CompletionStages in Play! with Akka

Tags: java, playframework, akka, completion-stage

In my web application, I am using Play! framework that builds on Akka for managing threads.
In a specific case, where I compose many CompletionStages that collects data from external services, I want to control the number of parallel requests in order not to overburden those external services.
One way to do this without changing the whole application is by controlling the thread pool size Akka uses.
Now I prepared two thread pools in akka like and tried to to switch between the two pools.
I am composing my CompletionStages using something like this:

```
CompletableFuture.completedFuture(firstResult)
                        .thenComposeAsync( firstResult -> { dostuff(firstResult);}
```

According to the Akka's [documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/dispatchers.html), this is how to set the current thread pool:

```
// this is scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
// for use with Futures, Scheduler, etc.
final ExecutionContext ex = system.dispatchers().lookup("my-dispatcher");
```

By watching my application, setting the context like this is not affecting the application and only the default dispatcher is being considered. Is there a way to set the size of the current pool in Akka dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass your custom `Executor` to the `thenComposeAsync` method:

```
final java.util.concurrent.Executor exec = system.dispatchers().lookup("my-dispatcher");

CompletableFuture.completedFuture(firstResult)
                 .thenComposeAsync(firstResult -> {
                   dostuff(firstResult);
                 }, exec);
```